# SQL query in Parallel.ForEach - Deadlock

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a static method which calls SQL SP inside a static method in a Parallel.ForEach loop. SP inserts data in 3 different tables. I am using Serializable Transaction level. But once in a while i am running into Deadlock situation.

I am thinking that if i make that method as Instance method or use simple ForEach, it may fix the problem.

Am i thinking right? Do i need to lock the list as well?

--Code--

```
Parallel.ForEach(MyConcurrentDictionary, MyElement =>
{
   if (MyElement.SomeProperty != SomeValue)
      {
         PublishMessage(MyElement);
      }
      else
      {
         InsertInDatabase(MyElement);

      }
}




public static void InsertInDatabase()
{
   DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
   DataTable t2 = new DataTable();
   DataTable t3 = new DataTable();


   CreateTable(T1);
   CreateTable(T2);
   CreateTable(T3);

   using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
      {
         try
            {
               conn.Open();

               // Begin transaction
               using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                  {
                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                     cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                     cmd.Connection = conn;
                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     cmd.CommandText = "SPName";
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T1", T1);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T2", T2);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T3", T3);
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                     transaction.Commit();

                }
           }

     }
}
```

Comment: Are you running all this in one transaction?

Comment: @Johann Blais - Each element creates its own Transaction. Transaction is created inside Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: This might just not be worth multithreading. If you're doing SQL inserts, you're probably going to be more IO bound than CPU bound.

Comment: Do you really need Serializable isolation; consider dropping down to Read Committed (the SQL Server default).

Comment: @ShellShock - I had Read Commited earlier but it was going into Deadlock situation so i changed it to Serializable.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post?

Comment: Any potential for the SP to induce deadlock?

Comment: @Brian Gideon - Edited the question with code

Comment: Also the code in the SP would be helpful. It is most likely there you will find the reason for the deadlock.

Comment: `IsolationLevel.Serializable` IS EVIL!!! It is the most lock-intensive setting you can get. Are you sure you want this? I doubt you do... Serializable in Sql Server will escalate locks very quickly to range and table locks. If you have any kind of throughput, deadlocks are sure to follow. `ReadCommitted` is what you're looking for, and it's the default isolation level in Sql server, `Serializable` is the default level in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your classes to non static methods that will help a lot. NEVER use statics in parallel it is just asking for trouble. And for safety try to use a thread save list aka an syncronized arraylist or a `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of T)`.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You get problems because you do not use any synchronization. The keyword `static` does not mean it is thread safe. Multiple threads from `Parallel.ForEach` can still access this method at the same time.

You have many options to synch that. But I will start with the easiest one, make it single threaded. If not possible, use `lock` or see [other options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

UPDATE
As noticed by @Colin, my answer works if you update the data somewhere. If everything is read-only, there is something else then. Check creation of the DataTable.

Comment: Not necessarily. There is nothing shown that would cause thread synchronisation issues in the C# code. (However, there is missing code which may have issues). It is perfectly fine to call a static method simultaneously if it is not sharing data with other threads (or any data that is shared is purely read only in all threads)

Comment: @Colin I assumed that creation of the DataTable is very likely to be thread unsafe.

Comment: Every single method is static. I hate it when people do that when it makes more sense to make methods instance method. These are not utility methods. These methods do database operations.

Comment: @Asdfg can you refactor that to instance methods or is it too much work?

Comment: Thats what i am going to do next.